# Change cell color in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page has a table with 3 columns, which are:

1. Member name
2. Obligatory to fill the form
3. Status

Column 2 has the values "Yes" or "No" and column 3 can have "Pending", "Started" or "Finished" values.

I want to make the color of the text in the column 3 change depending on the status, so I did the following js.

```
$("td[headers ='STATUS']").each(function () {
   if($(this).text() == 'Pending'){
       $(this).css("color", "red");
   }
   else if($(this).text() == 'Finished'){
      $(this).css("color", "green");
   }
   else if($(this).text() == 'Started'){
      $(this).css("color", "#B8B800");
   };
});
```

It is working as intended. But now I want to only change the colors of the column 3, when column 2 has a value "Yes" for obligatory, else it is supposed to stay black.

Is there a way to mix my "if" to check the other column?

Comment: Unrelated, but you might want to (a) map the text to the color and remove a bunch of duplication, and then (b) map to a semantically-named style instead of a color... like, say, `Pending`, `Finished`, etc. You see where this is going.

Comment: `if ($(this).prev().text() === "Yes") { /* your if/else block here */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change my concept, to run on rows, not on all cells, and do my checks "per line".

This is what it will look like:

JS:

```
    $(function () {
    $("tbody tr").each(function () {
        var cols = $(this).children("td");
        if ($(cols[1]).text() == "Yes") {
            var statusEle = $(cols[2]);
            switch (statusEle.text()) {
                case 'Pending':
                    statusEle.css("color", "red");
                    break;
                case 'Finished':
                    statusEle.css("color", "green");
                    break;
                case 'Started':
                    statusEle.css("color", "#B8B800");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Is Obligated</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Single</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CRAP</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Finished</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/6f00tkr7/)

Comment: Thanks, bro! Seeing this makes me realize I need to study a lot more.

Comment: Its a big world out there ;) I've studied a lot with help of SO community. I love this community, so I give back when I can.